# Makefile: Check write permission to directory

Tags: linux, permissions, makefile

Is there a way to, in a Makefile rule, check if it has permission to write to a specified directory? This is a small part of the Makefile I'm writing:

```
APP_NAME = electro
CC = gcc
C_FLAGS = -Wall
LIB_DIR = lib
SRC_DIR = src
INST_DIR = /usr/bin
INST_LIBDIR = /usr/lib
LIBS = libcomponent.so libpower.so libresistance.so
L_FLAGS = -lresistance -lpower -lcomponent

.PHONY: lib

lib:
    @$(MAKE) --directory=$(LIB_DIR)

install:    $(SRC_DIR)/main.c lib
    (cd $(LIB_DIR); cp $(LIBS) $(INST_LIBDIR))
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $(INST_DIR)/$(APP_NAME) $(L_FLAGS) $< 
    @echo "$(APP_NAME) installed successfully."
```

The 'install' rule will obviously fail if the user doesn't have permission to write to /usr/lib and /usr/bin. Is there a way to check this permission before executing these two lines and in that case output an appropriate error message (perhaps something along the lines of "You do not have sufficient permissions to run this command")?

Comment: Be aware that these checks aren't worth much on Cygwin.  It may be better to just fail to write there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shell's /bin/test or /bin/[ will let you `/bin/test -d /path/to/foo -a -w /path/to/foo`, even if make doesn't by itself.

An alternate way to make a directory accessible is to try to create it with `mkdir -p` before testing whether it's writable.  I've been known to do the following:

```
mkdir -p ${TARGETDIR} && test -w ${TARGETDIR}
```

If the first command fails, the second isn't tried.  If the directory already exists, `mkdir -p` will succeed.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks!
I used: if [ -w /usr/lib ] && [ -w /usr/bin ]

Comment: Don't underestimate the value of `mkdir -p`.  For example, if your documentation needs to be installed in `${PREFIX}/share/${PKGNAME}/html/`, it's way easier to run a single `mkdir -p` rather than test and create each individual part of that path.  If you real goal is to "write to ${PATH} if possible", this is a faster way to reach it.

Comment: @yzfr1, it's not a big deal, but `if [ -w /usr/lib ] && [ -w /usr/bin ]` does use more resources than the format I mentioned in my answer. By joining two `[` tests with `&&`, you run the `/bin/[` binary *twice* if you're in a POSIX shell. Of course, if you're in bash, `[` is built-in, so the performance difference would be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You do things like that more or less by embedding small bits of shell scripts into your makefile.

Comment: well yes, I am aware of that. What I'm looking for is the specific piece shell code that I could use to accomplish that.